# Can I split compressed files into json components in Camel via Spring DSL

Tags: json, apache-camel

In a nutshell, I need to take a gzipped file containing json very similar to this example, unzip it (I know how to do that), get each json object as a string and push it to AMQ from where it will be popped to a webservice. I'm fine with all of this with one object, but I will be receiving a file that represents an array. If this were an array of strings or xml, I see how Camel processes it, but I don't see a way to split json.  Also, this will require streaming as these files can be very large.  *Edited to try to make request clearer, and provide a sample json.*

```
 [
{
    "rickenbackerRepair": {
        "estimateId": 22788411
    },
    "repairShop": {
        "inspectionSite": {
            "inspectionDate": ""
        },
        "repairFacility": {
            "companyIdCode": "",
            "companyName": "",
            "city": "",
            "stateProvince": "",
            "zipPostalCode": "",
            "country": ""
        },
        "repairInformation": {
            "guitarDateInShop": "",
            "guitarTimeInShop": "",
            "authorizationMemo": "",
            "guitarTargetCompletionDate": "",
            "guitarTargetCompletionTime": "",
            "guitarCompletionDate": "",
            "guitarCompletionTime": ""
        },
        "locationOfguitar": {
            "city": "",
            "stateProvince": "",
            "zipPostalCode": "",
            "country": ""
        }
    },  
    "instrumentIdentifier": {
        "guitar": {
            "claimRelated": {
                "primaryPointOfImpact": "",
                "secondaryPointOfImpact": ""
            },
            "identification": {
                "databaseguitarCode": "",
                "manufacturingStateProvince": "",
                "serialNumber": "",
                "guitarCondition": "",
                "productionDate": "",
                "year": "",
                "model": "",
                "guitarType": "",
                "bodyStyle": "",
                "trimCode": "",
                "trimColor": "",
                "optionsList": ""
            }
        }
    },
    "lin": [{
        "internalControl": {
            "lineIndicator": ""
        },
        "part": {
            "description": {
                "partType": "",
                "descriptionJudgmentFlag": "",
                "oemPartNumber": "",
                "priceIncludedIndicator": "",
                "alternatePartIndicator": "",
                "taxableFlag": "",
                "databasePartPrice": "",
                "actualPartPrice": "",
                "priceJudgmentFlag": "",
                "certifiedFlag": "",
                "quantity": ""
            },
            "nonOemSupplier": {
                "companyIdCode": "",
                "nonOemPartNumber": "",
                "nonOemSupplierUserOverride": "",
                "nonOemSupplierMemo": ""
            },
            "adjustment": {
                "percent": "",
                "amount": ""
            }
        },
        "labor": {
            "description": {
                "type": "",
                "actualHours": "",
                "hoursJudgmentFlag": "",
                "typeJudgmentFlag": ""
            },
            "miscSublet": {
                "amount": "",
                "subletFlag": ""
            }
        }
    }],

    "stl": {
        "subtotal": [{
            "totalType": "",
            "totalTypeCode": "",
            "subtotalDetail": {
                "taxableAmount": ""
            }
        }]
    }
},
{
    "rickenbackerRepair": {
        "estimateId": 22788412
    },
    "repairShop": {
        "inspectionSite": {
            "inspectionDate": ""
        },
        "repairFacility": {
            "companyIdCode": "",
            "companyName": "",
            "city": "",
            "stateProvince": "",
            "zipPostalCode": "",
            "country": ""
        },
        "repairInformation": {
            "guitarDateInShop": "",
            "guitarTimeInShop": "",
            "authorizationMemo": "",
            "guitarTargetCompletionDate": "",
            "guitarTargetCompletionTime": "",
            "guitarCompletionDate": "",
            "guitarCompletionTime": ""
        },
        "locationOfguitar": {
            "city": "",
            "stateProvince": "",
            "zipPostalCode": "",
            "country": ""
        }
    },  
    "instrumentIdentifier": {
        "guitar": {
            "claimRelated": {
                "primaryPointOfImpact": "",
                "secondaryPointOfImpact": ""
            },
            "identification": {
                "databaseguitarCode": "",
                "manufacturingStateProvince": "",
                "serialNumber": "",
                "guitarCondition": "",
                "productionDate": "",
                "year": "",
                "model": "",
                "guitarType": "",
                "bodyStyle": "",
                "trimCode": "",
                "trimColor": "",
                "optionsList": ""
            }
        }
    },
    "lin": [{
        "internalControl": {
            "lineIndicator": ""
        },
        "part": {
            "description": {
                "partType": "",
                "descriptionJudgmentFlag": "",
                "oemPartNumber": "",
                "priceIncludedIndicator": "",
                "alternatePartIndicator": "",
                "taxableFlag": "",
                "databasePartPrice": "",
                "actualPartPrice": "",
                "priceJudgmentFlag": "",
                "certifiedFlag": "",
                "quantity": ""
            },
            "nonOemSupplier": {
                "companyIdCode": "",
                "nonOemPartNumber": "",
                "nonOemSupplierUserOverride": "",
                "nonOemSupplierMemo": ""
            },
            "adjustment": {
                "percent": "",
                "amount": ""
            }
        },
        "labor": {
            "description": {
                "type": "",
                "actualHours": "",
                "hoursJudgmentFlag": "",
                "typeJudgmentFlag": ""
            },
            "miscSublet": {
                "amount": "",
                "subletFlag": ""
            }
        }
    }],

    "stl": {
        "subtotal": [{
            "totalType": "",
            "totalTypeCode": "",
            "subtotalDetail": {
                "taxableAmount": ""
            }
        }]
    }
}
]
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you have working and you need guidance on. If you don't know how to format json on SO, put it anyway. We can fix it later! :)

Comment: Thank you, magically I got it to look ok.  I know that this json is more complex than most samples, but I did not want to find out that what worked with a fairly simple example failed with a larger one.  This example is a completely made-up example so if it doesn't make business sense, that's why,...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a `jsonpath` expression to split the incoming message (file) and process each element individually.

```
<route>
  <from uri="file://path" />
  <split>
    <jsonpath>$.</jsonpath>
    <to uri="direct:doSomething">
  </split>
</route>
```

Comment: Ok, I love this answer, but I had previously read that I could not do this with streaming.  It's possible that this is out of date though.

Comment: I read the same, but this isn't doing streaming (to my knowledge). Because this doesn't do streaming, it may present issues when dealing with "large" json files, as memory consumption may spike. If so, another approach might be necessary.And that would require additional work dealing with the stream.

Comment: The last requirement specifies that we must be able to stream this because of the number of json objects.

Comment: Eek! Missed that point. I'm afraid that there are no insights I can share in this case.

Comment: jsonpath has no streaming support yet - but a PR is in the works: https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/pull/93